# What's the best way to send in multiple coordinates in a JSON to RethinkDB in order to create an r.polygon?

Tags: json, express, polygon, geospatial, rethinkdb

I'm using an Express server with RethinkDB, and I want to send in multiple coordinates into my 'locations' table on RethinkDB and create an r.polygon(). I understand how to do the query via RethinkDB's data explorer , but I'm having trouble figuring out how to send it via JSON from the client to the server and insert it through my query there.

I basically want to do this:

```
r.db('places').table('locations').insert({
  name: req.body.name,
  bounds: r.polygon(req.body.bounds)
})
```

where req.body.bounds looks like this:

```
[long, lat],[long, lat], [long, lat]
```

I can't send it in as a string because then it gets read as one single input instead of three arrays. I'm sure there's a 'right in front of me' way, but I'm drawing a blank.

What's the best way to do this?

**Edit:** To clarify, my question is, what should my JSON look like and how should it be received on my server?

This is what RethinkDB wants in order to make a polygon:

```
r.polygon([lon1, lat1], [lon2, lat2], [lon3, lat3], ...) → polygon
```

As per the suggestion, I've added in r.args() to my code:

```
 r.db('places').table('locations').insert({
  name: req.body.name,
  bounds: r.polygon(r.args(req.body.bounds))
})
```

**Edit**
Ok, I was dumb and had a typo in one of my coordinates!

**Sending it as an array of arrays and wrapping it in r.args() on the server side works.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is `r.args` to unpack the array into arguments for r.polygon. https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/args/

With assumption that req.body.bounds is:

```
[[long, lat],[long, lat], [long, lat]]
```

And you are submit a raw JSON string from client.

You first need to decode the JSON payload, and get the `bounds` field, wrap it with `args` as following:

```
var body = JSON.parse(req.body)
r.db('places').table('locations').insert({
  name: req.body.name,
  bounds: r.polygon(r.args(body.bounds))
})
```

Comment: `{
 "name": "Location One",
        "bounds": [-110.798849, 45.82401], [-110.71609, 45.89191], [-110.67489, 45.83358]

}`

That's what I want my JSON to look like, but it's not letting me send it through. I've tried wrapping it in a string, another array as well as a couple other things. I haven't been successful.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. You control the data format that you submit to your Express server. And you can decode it, right? 

So just ensure that you can run something like:


    var body = JSON.parse(req.body)
    //Now body.bound should be an array 
    console.log(body.bounds)
    => [[-110.798849, 45.82401], [-110.71609, 45.89191], [-110.67489, 45.83358]]

Then wrap it in r.args

r.db('places').table('locations').insert({
  name: req.body.name,
  bounds: r.polygon(r.args((body.bounds))
})

Comment: Sorry, I realize now that my question may not have been clear. I've been trying to send in my data in that exact format (an array of arrays), but I keep getting a syntax error:
`{ [SyntaxError: Unexpected number]
  body: '{\n\t"name": "Test",\n    "bounds": [[-111.52624, 40.61389],[-111.582756, 40.61271],[-111-52858, 40.61181]]\n}\n ',
  status: 400,
  statusCode: 400 }
`
So I've tried doing different things like wrapping the whole thing in a string, or making each of the coordinates a string, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Hmm, I see that you have `\n\t` before JSON key and bunch of space after `:`. And `-111-52858` isn't a number. The error you get is about fail to decode `JSON`. If you can submit this string, it should work: `JSON.parse('{"name":"Test","bounds":[[-111.52624,40.61389],[-111.582756,40.61271],[-52969,40.61181]]}')` . Notice that you have to remove the `\n\t` around `key:value` notation.

Comment: Hey, I just re-read your question and realize you figure it out about typo of `number -111-52858`. Wrapping in `r.args` works for you now. Please mark this as answer if possible :)